# C# Reflection-based CSV Parser

Tags: c#, parsing, error-handling, csv, reflection

I've been trying to make a C# version of my [Java CSV Parser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244432/java-reflection-based-csv-parser) using C# specific idioms.

Here is the full code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CSV
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public sealed class ParseException : Exception
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public ParseException()
        {
        }
        
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public ParseException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
        {
        }
    }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// This Exception is raised when a type <c>T</c> is not supported by <see cref="Convert.ChangeType(object?,Type)"/>
    /// nor has a custom parser been registered via <see cref="Parsers.RegisterParser{T}(Converter{string,T})"/> for the type.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class NoSuchParserException : Exception
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public NoSuchParserException()
        {
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public NoSuchParserException(Type t) : base($"There are no supported parsers for {t}")
        {
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This attribute may be applied to any property of a class or struct to indicate that the custom name should
    /// be matched against the headers of the CSV file instead of the name of the attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    /// <example>
    /// <c>[CSV.PropertyName("value")] public int Num { get; set; }</c>
    /// </example>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public sealed class PropertyNameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the property.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="PropertyNameAttribute"/> with the specified property name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the property.</param>
        public PropertyNameAttribute(string name) => Name = name;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A struct for accessing the map of parsers used by <see cref="Parser{TRow}"/>
    /// </summary>
    public readonly struct Parsers
    {
        internal static readonly Dictionary<Type, Converter<string, object>> Dict = 
            new Dictionary<Type, Converter<string, object>>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Globally registers a parser for <typeparamref name="T"/>, overriding any parser which may exist for the type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parser">a <c>Converter</c> from a string to an arbitrary type <c>T</c></param>
        /// <typeparam name="T">a type to make available for parsing into</typeparam>
        public static void RegisterParser<T>(Converter<string, T> parser)
        {
            object CovarianceCaster(string s) => parser(s);
            Dict[typeof(T)] = CovarianceCaster;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This class allows CSV text strings to be conveniently and easily parsed into an Enumerable sequence of objects of type <c>TRow</c>
    /// </summary>
    ///
    /// <para>
    /// By default, CSV.Parser supports parsing all types supported by <see cref="Convert.ChangeType(object?,Type)"/>
    /// Parsers for other types may be added via <see cref="Parsers.RegisterParser{T}(Converter{string,T})"/>.
    /// </para>
    ///
    /// <example>
    /// Suppose there exists the following struct <c>Foo</c>:
    /// <code>
    /// public struct Foo
    /// {
    ///     [CSV.PropertyName("Value")] public float X { get; set; }
    ///     public string Name { get; set; }
    /// }
    /// </code>
    /// Given a <see cref="TextReader"/> whose contents are
    /// <code>
    /// Name,Value
    /// hello,3.14
    /// world
    /// </code>
    /// each line can be parsed into a <c>Foo</c> object using
    /// <code>
    /// var csv = new CSV.Parser(reader)
    /// foreach (var foo in csv) Console.WriteLine(foo);
    /// </code>
    /// </example>
    /// 
    /// <typeparam name="TRow">
    /// a type that satisfies the following properties:
    /// <list type="bullet">
    ///     <item>It has a no-argument constructor (satisfies the <c>new()</c> constraint)</item>
    ///     <item>Any property which should be affected should have an accessor</item>
    /// </list>
    /// </typeparam>
    public class Parser<TRow> : IEnumerable<TRow> where TRow : new()
    {
        private readonly TextReader _reader;
        private readonly string _delimiter;
        private readonly List<string> _headers;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new CSV.Parser instance from the specified <c>reader</c> whose lines may be parsed into <c>TRow</c> instances
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">a <c>TextReader</c> containing N lines of text, each line containing M data fields
        /// separated by a <c>delimiter</c></param>
        /// <param name="delimiter">the delimiter to use</param>
        public Parser(TextReader reader, string delimiter = ",")
        {
            _reader = reader;
            _delimiter = delimiter;
            _headers = _reader.ReadLine()?.Split(delimiter).ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Ignores the specified next number of lines. Useful for possible inclusion of metadata in the CSV data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numberOfLines">the number of lines to skip</param>
        /// <returns>this CSV.Parser instance</returns>
        public Parser<TRow> Skip(int numberOfLines)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) { _reader.ReadLine(); }
            return this;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the next line of the associated <see cref="TextReader"/> into a <c>TRow</c> object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The parsed TRow object</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ParseException">There is no valid parser for one of the types of the fields of
        /// <typeparamref name="TRow"/>, or a parser threw an Exception while parsing</exception>
        public TRow ReadLine()
        {
            var line = _reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null) return default;

            var split = line.Split(_delimiter);
            object row = new TRow();

            foreach (var prop in typeof(TRow).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite))
            {
                var attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyNameAttribute>();
                var name = attr == null ? prop.Name : attr.Name;

                var idx = _headers.IndexOf(name);
                if (idx >= split.Length) continue;

                var parsed = idx == -1 ? null : TryParse(split[idx].Trim(' ', '\"'), prop.PropertyType);
                prop.SetValue(row, parsed);
            }

            return (TRow) row;
        }
        
        private static object TryParse(string s, Type t)
        {
            if (Parsers.Dict.ContainsKey(t))
            {
                try
                {
                    return Parsers.Dict[t].Invoke(s);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new ParseException($"The parser for {t} failed", e);
                }
            }

            try
            {
                return s != "" ? Convert.ChangeType(s, t) : null;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new NoSuchParserException(t);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an <see cref="IEnumerator{T}"/> by repeatedly invoking <see cref="Parser{TRow}.ReadLine()"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>an <see cref="IEnumerator{T}"/> of all the parsed rows</returns>
        public IEnumerator<TRow> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (var row = ReadLine(); !row.Equals(default(TRow)); row = ReadLine())
            {
                yield return row;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

My primary concerns are idiomatically implementing exception handling. In particular, I was wondering if

- `NoSuchParserException` should be removed and use `ParseException` as a catch all Exception for the class
- my implementation of `TryParse` could be improved / designed better

I was also wondering how I should go about the case where the number of properties in `TRow` is not equal to the number of headers in the CSV data. I'm not sure if I should ignore the extraneous headers or properties, add an Enum option, or always throw an Exception.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. Do you want to port and redesign the CSV parser at the same time? What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic `TryParse` signature is `public bool TryParse(string input, out T result)`. It should never throw; that's what regular `Parse` is for. Return `true` if it succeeds and `false` otherwise, with `result` being set to the parsed value or `default` respectively. If you really do want to distinguish between the cases "there exists a converter but the string simply couldn't be parsed" and "there doesn't even exist a converter for that type", then I suppose you can keep those exceptions, but I'd still like to see some way of indicating whether or not the parse succeeded given there exists a parser for that type. null is not a particularly strong indicator since it's conceivable that someone might want to encode null in their CSV file.

XML documentation is a good habit to get into so I'm glad to see that. I would add a note to the docs for `ReadLine` indicating that it'll return `default(TRow)` when it hits the end of the text reader.

Which brings me to something that sticks out, and that's the end-of-text-reader condition: your mechanism for that is to return the default value of `TRow` from `ReadLine`. What happens if `TRow` is a value type and I happen to read a line that's intended to populate an instance of `TRow` with default values? For example, if `TRow` is `Point` and my CSV line is `0,0`, it looks like the parser enumerator will end prematurely. Perhaps `ReadLine` should return a flag indicating whether something was actually read or not. Or maybe define a `TryReadLine` in the same manner as `TryParse` which returns a bool indicating whether it worked.

You will never need to instantiate `Parsers` so it should be a `static class` instead of a `readonly struct`.

If you're not using the new C# 8.0 nullable references, then you should be throwing `ArgumentNullException`s in the Parser constructor if any of those parameters are null.

`_headers` can be null but you're not checking for null anywhere; although I suppose you can reason that it will always be non-null in the parts where it's actually used, in which case I'd document that with an assertion.

You will read a lot of wisdom saying that premature optimization is the root of all evil, but here is a case where it's possibly warranted:

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(TRow).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanWrite))
```

Reflection is super slow and the properties associated with `TRow` will not change during runtime, so you can cache the result of `typeof(TRow).GetProperties()`. Likewise for `prop.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyNameAttribute>()`. It's up to you/your stakeholders whether your current solution is fast enough. If it isn't, look into caching those things.